# App freeze when adding azure backend table query

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services, freeze

Lets to the point, this is my code :

```
    private MobileServiceClient mClient;
    private MobileServiceTable<tblClass> mTable;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit me", false)){
            finish();
            return;
        }

        try {
            mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                    "https://applink.azurewebsites.net",
                    this
            );
            mTable = mClient.getTable(tblClass.class);

            // when this line added, the app freezes, with no information on the logcat
            List<tblClass> results = mTable
                    .execute()         
                    .get();
            // end of the line

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MobileServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

i already try get the return data to a list using this

```
Toast.makeText(this, results.indexOf(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and the result is still the same, the app freezes
i've already try to debug it on many android versions (from 4.4 to 7.0) too, can someone tell me why this is happening? im just learning android in one month.

UPDATE

this is the last logCat before the app freezes

```
    07-30 01:50:30.168 24014-24014/id.co.mandiri.e_absenmandiri I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
    07-30 01:50:30.332 24014-24014/id.co.mandiri.e_absenmandiri W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
    07-30 01:50:30.604 24014-24027/id.co.mandiri.e_absenmandiri I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1973(388KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 20% free, 1579KB/1983KB, paused 5.293ms total 20.441ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run your query(long time operation in other words) in the main thead, which is responsible for UI updates. You need to start another thread using AsyncTask, Loaders or simply creating a new Thread implementation.